# mac osx lion security configuration guide

Tags: security, macos

I could find the security configuration guide for mac osx versions at http://www.apple.com/support/security/guides/ however, I can't find any for OS X Lion. Any one know if it is in the works or if it is moved else where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct.  They're sadly slow to publish this info.  Try this: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.21/21.02/Security/index.html

Cheers!