# Where are updated Apple security guidelines for recent OS X versions?

Tags: macos, security

Pardon my paranoia; but with an 80,000-strong[[#]](https://www.apple.com/about/job-creation/) global work force, one would think the need to cover important security guidelines for users would easily be met with each new OS X release. Yet a glance at [apple's security page](https://ssl.apple.com/support/security/guides/) reveals that the last update was for 10.6 Snow Leopard, a long, long time ago for internet age.

So where are the security config guide updates for Lion, Mountain Lion & Mavericks?

Comment: Please keep the question focused on the thing you are looking for (security config guides for recent OS X releases).

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but an upgrade. At the time of Lion inception, and at that time Internet aggressivness the lack was large. Now we are many years later and many major OS X versions away in outer space without the usual relevant documentation.

Comment: See this related question at the time of Lion: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/48853/22003 .